# Delete record from database if expired

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to set this up so that if the record is expired it will be deleted, I know my connection is good because this code works

```
mysqli_query($resDB,"DELETE FROM downloads WHERE downloads='1'");
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with time, is it possible to use the less than sign in queries? This is what I have so far.

```
mysqli_query($resDB,"DELETE FROM downloads WHERE expires < time()");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. It returns the current UTC time. Your expires field is that. `time()` also is that.

```
WHERE expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: thank you that worked, I will accept as answer in 10 minutes when it lets me

Comment: Many useful date/time functions and their arguments and output: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, first of all you need to create a field, (Such as TimeStamp) though i prefer DateTime.
Whenever you insert a new row in table "**downloads**"
you ll have to give it an expiration date.

which you will do by using the following:

```
INSERT INTO downloads (Download_ID, ExpiresOn) VALUES( 5, DATE_ADD(NOW(),interval +1 month) );
```

so, whenever you want to delete an expired download_id
you will have to

```
DELETE FROM downloads WHERE ExpiresOn < NOW() LIMIT 1;
```

hope this helps :)

ofcourse there are different type of solutions for this prob, you ll have to give a better explanation of your problem and what you want to achieve. :)

cheers^^